# Hide sidebar on Tribe Events Calendar with Roots/Sage Wordpress template

Tags: wordpress, roots-sage

I need to hide the sidebar from the Tribe Events calendar pages using a Roots/Sage Wordpress template. I can achieve this using:
'tribe_is_upcoming' in the display_sidebar function, but this also removes it from the Blog pages. Any ideas how I can hide it from the Tribe Events pages but still display on my Blog pages?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to use the functions:

```
function display_sidebar() {
  static $display;

  isset($display) || $display = !in_array(true, [
  // The sidebar will NOT be displayed if ANY of the following return true.
  // @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags
  is_404(),
  is_front_page(),
  is_page(),
  tribe_is_month(),
  tribe_is_upcoming(),
  tribe_is_day()
 ]);

 return apply_filters('sage/display_sidebar', $display);
}
```